# Packet relay to bridge two networks (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, c#-4.0, winsock

I have 2 computers and a server.

- Computer 1 has an IP address of 10.0.0.1
- Computer 2 has an IP address of 10.0.1.1

They're both on different networks.

A server is connected to both networks.

- LAN1 IP is 10.0.0.253
- LAN2 IP is 10.0.1.253

I want to send a packet from 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.253 and have that packet relayed via 10.0.1.253 to 10.0.1.1

How can this be achieved in C#?

Thank you

Comment: I do not believe it is possible to *bridge* between the two networks without help of an outside driver/stack (perhaps including Windows ICS/networking sharing support?), but a *proxy/forward* is most certainly possible - what have you tried?

Comment: You cannot do this in C#. Managing network traffic happens at the driver level and as such must be coded in an unmanaged language like C/C++.

Comment: Do you have communication between the two hosts now, or are you just hoping to achieve this through C#? Since 10.x.x.x isn't a publicly routeable address, there's a fair bit of network configuration to do here before you worry about programmatically sending packets if the networks were disjoint

Comment: @glace 10.0.0.1 can't ping 10.0.1.1, but it can ping 10.0.0.253. 10.0.1.1 can't ping 10.0.0.1 either, but can ping 10.0.1.253. Since 10.0.0.253 and 10.0.1.253 are two network cards on the same server I was  hoping to be able to receive packets over 10.0.0.253 and relay them over 10.0.1.253.

Comment: @pst so far, I wrote a basic application to listen for data on any IP, and then sent it back to 10.0.1.1, and put it on the server. Then I wrote a basic application to send a "hello" to 10.0.0.253 which I ran on 10.0.0.1 and an application that listens on 10.0.1.1. Since both computers can simultaneously connect to the server I would have thought this would be possible.

Comment: Just to add. I wrote an application to send a message to 10.0.0.253 and ran it from 10.0.0.1 the relay application received the message but didn't transmit. I sent a message from 10.0.1.1 to 10.0.1.253 the relay application received the message but didn't transmit. I ran the relay application locally and sent a message to myself and it continually relayed the message. To make it obvious it was relaying, I added the time to the message. This demonstrates that both computers can talk to the relay, and that the relay does in fact relay. So there's something missing still...

Comment: @Hatrix What subnets are your two ethernet interfaces on? If the subnet masks of each host is 255.255.255.255, host 10.0.0.1 will only be able to talk to 10.0.0.x, and host 10.0.1.1 can only talk to 10.0.1.x. If I were you, I'd just setup an ethernet bridge between the two interfaces. That way, they should be able to pass frames between them and communication between the hosts should be now be trivial.

Comment: @glace 10.0.0.1/255.255.255.0 10.0.1.1/255.0.0.0

Comment: @Hatrix I mistyped in my previous comment, I meant 255.255.255.0. However, can you explain your choice of the 255.0.0.0 subnet mask for me? I would just put them both on the 255.255.255.0 subnet then bridge the connections. This is getting quite far out of the realm of C# troubleshooting, though.

Comment: @glace 255.0.0.0 subnet wasn't picked specifically. When the DNS was setup it was the default entry. I just never changed it.

Comment: @glace I changed it now so they're all 255.255.255.0

Comment: @Hatrix Now try bridging the connections. That's the key here, so the two subnets can communicate.

Comment: Could you not code the C# application to listen on 10.0.0.253 and 10.0.1.254. When each client connects, store the socket and client IP address in a client object.

Now, whenever you receive data from 1 socket, handle the data, passing it to the other client object and then send it down the socket.